# Is there a way to "pre-filter" Get-WinEvent output DURING the query?

Tags: windows, powershell

Consider the following MWE:

```
# Current time is the end time of when we look for events
$now = Get-Date
$around = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 7200
# Define start time, too
$before = $now.Subtract($around)
Write-Host "Events from $before to $now"
# List events from those two logs
$rawevents = Get-WinEvent -LogName @("Application", "System", "PowerShellCore/Operational", "Windows PowerShell")
# Just show the number of events from all the logs
Write-Host $rawevents.Count
# Filter down the list by creation time of the event record
$fltevents = $rawevents|Where-Object -Property TimeCreated -LE $now|Where-Object -Property TimeCreated -GE $before
# Show filtered count
Write-Host $fltevents.Count
```

Now the issue here is that I haven't found a way to filter down the records returned by `Get-WinEvent` *during* the initial invocation and therefore have to resort to using `Where-Object`. But arguably for bigger logs it could be a lot faster to limit the query to a given time range. As an example, the count for `$rawevents` is ~50000 on my system, but usually less than 20 remain after filtering.

With [`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) there's the `-Before` and `-After` argument which can be used "up front", but

1. I don't see this cmdlet in PowerShell Core 7.2.6
2. It's documentation states:

   > `Get-EventLog` uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet instead.

**Question:** So is there a way to achieve the same without wasting system resources by throwing away the majority of events anyway? I.e. filtering *while* querying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979580/ps-using-get-winevent-with-filterxpath-and-datetime-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your initial call of `Get-WinEvent` to include the `$before` and `$now` variables. Also you can use `-FilterHashTable` and then pass the lognames inside the hashtable as well as the start and end time of what events you are looking for.

```
$rawevents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{Logname="Application", "System", "PowerShellCore/Operational", "Windows PowerShell";StartTime=$before;EndTime=$now}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you this seems to be spot on what I was looking for.